# Content is off screen in android

Tags: android, android-layout

I have 3 elements in a `LinearLayout` that need to fit on the screen, currently they do not.

Here is how I want it to look

`TextView` -- `TextView` -- `EditText`

However the 2nd `TextView` is rather long and it pushes the `EditText` off the screen

So it ends up looking like this

`TextView` --- (end of screen)| `TextView` --------|(end of screen) `EditText`

I've looked around for a while and I can't seem to find a solution to what should be an easy fix. If this is a duplicate please feel free to link me to the question with the appropriate answer because I was unable to find it on my own.

Here is the code, thanks for the help

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_gravity="center"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/iline_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

<LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/ll3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView5"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/b"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView6"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/distance_edge"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ems="4" />
</LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

In the end I would like the 2nd `TextView` to take up the same space 33% of the width as the others and just wrap the text as many times as necessary to do this

**Edit**

The first text view is only a letter B) so i had to set wrap content on that, then the others worked fine

Here is the code

```
<LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/ll3"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView5"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"                
            android:text="@string/b"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView6"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@string/distance_edge"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText2"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:ems="4" />
    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Hey one last question so I don't have to start another thread. You see how the very bottom of @mmBs string is being cut off? the word text is half there. How do I fix that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Now it is correct for sure - I've checked it in IDE.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/iline_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/ll3"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_gravity="center" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView5"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="some long, long, long text"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView6"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="some long, long, long, long, long, long, long, long, long text"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText2"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:ems="4" />
    </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

[image: Screen]

Comment: nope, but i edited my post because I think there is something going on with the layouts outside this one.

Comment: Copy and paste my code. In my IDE everything works as you need.

Comment: yes, and it would. Except you are missing a very crucial point. The 2nd string is like a fifth of the length of my 2nd string. Try putting in something 5 times as long

Comment: you're right it works, thank you. Sorry I wasted so much time with this it drove me absolutely insane. Now I just need to adjust the first width to what I want because It's far too long. So I guess setting the layouts weight is what was messing things up?

Comment: The problem was in nested LinearLayout with id ll3, because in this case `layout_width` couldn't be `warp_content`. Weights on each element (TV1, TV2, ET) are vital to declare this layout correctly.
I'm glad I could help;)

Comment: Hey one last question so I don't have to start another thread. You see how the very bottom of your string is being cut off? the word text is half there. How do I fix that?

Comment: Set `android_height` parameters on TV1, TV2 and ET to `match_parent`.

Answer (score 2):

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/ll3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:weightSum="3"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView5"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="@string/b"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView6"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="@string/distance_edge"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:ems="4" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Hey Hoan! Nice to see you again, unfortunately your solution does not work either. It actually makes the entire layout dissapear from my screen.

Comment: Is this layout part of a bigger layout?

Comment: I edited the answer, I cut and paste and forgot to make layout_witdth = "0dp"

Comment: yes, the complete code is far too long to post. It is the 3rd linear layout nested inside another linear layout, nested inside a scrollview. There are over 25 total linear layouts inside this fragment

Comment: I just edited the answer again, hopefully it will work this time

Comment: @mmBs it is exactly the same code I had before and it did not work.

Comment: That is strange, remove gravity center and see if that does anything.

Comment: edited the post to show the parent layouts that are also controlling it. That's probably where Im messing this up and why we've wasted so much time

Comment: Why do you have android:layout_height="0dp" in your Linear layout?

Comment: that was the original, code I only edited to show the "parent" code, I'll edit it now to show my current code. Sorry

Comment: android:layout_height="0dp" is exactly what makes the layout "disappear."  It's really there, but it's 0dp tall, so of course you can't see it.  I removed that from my answer as well.

Comment: @MarsAtomic I do not know if this is a complete layout. He stated the complete layout is very long. So this layout maybe part of a layout and this layout_weight is 1 so there is a need for layout_height="0dp"

Comment: No actually that's where you guys are wrong, this is a "horizontal" alignment in a "LinearLayout" with a "vertical" alignment. If we make the height equal to 0dp there is no issue. If we make the width equal to 0dp it dissapears. I just changed it in my code because it made my layout go insane when I put height to "wrap_content" and my width to "0dp"

Comment: In your current code you should have android:layout_width="wrap_content" instead of android:layout_width="0dp" and android:layout_height="0dp" as you have originally, but I do not understand why it is there unless you have other this linear layout is part of a larger layout.

Comment: I was wrong, and it appears that setting the layout weight is what was causing me so much trouble I will momentarily update the code to show what finally worked, thank you so much for everything all of you

Answer (score 1):

Try setting weight attributes for your text views and edit text.  The output can look a bit awkward depending on what your strings are and how they wrap.

```
<LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/ll3"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView5"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.33"
            android:text="Some string"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView6"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.33"
            android:text="some really, really, really, long string"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText2"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.33"
            android:ems="4" />
    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: sorry, it didn't work. The exact same problem, the middle one expands and pushes the other two off the screen, it does however new line once. Also it barks at me for using nested weights saying "its bad for performance".

Comment: Did you see that my example does not have a weight attribute in the enclosing LinearLayout?  If there's any way to use some layout other than another linear layout above the enclosing linear layout, you'll be in good shape as far as the warning goes.  Works perfectly on my end.